# How do I solve $\int e^{\frac{1}{x}}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to solve this as part of some problem, but I'm not able to.

Can anyone integrate the above problem?

Please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion? What have you done yourself?

Comment: I tried by various substitutions but I just arrive at some dead end.

Answer (score 9):

$$\int e^{1/x} \, dx=e^{1/x} x-\text{Ei}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) + c$$

where $\operatorname{Ei}(x)$ is the *exponential integral function* defined as

$$\operatorname{Ei}(x) = - \int_{-x}^\infty \frac{e^{-t} dt}t$$

$\operatorname{Ei}(x)$ is a non-elementary function, and we can only evaluate it using numerical methods.

Comment: Sorry. I am not following it. You mean the solution doesnt exist?

Comment: @MB17 No, just that the integral can't be expressed in terms of elementary functions

Answer (score 6):

Make a substitution of $x = \tan \theta$, then you obtain

$$ I = \int e^{\cot \theta} \sec^2\theta \ \ d\theta $$

Integrate by parts with $u$ being the exponential:

$$ uv - \int{v \ du} = \tan \theta \ e^{\cot \theta} + \int{\dfrac{e^{\cot \theta}}{\sin \theta \cos \theta} \ d \theta} $$

Make a substitution of $u = \cot \theta \implies du = -\csc^2 \theta$, noting that $\tan \theta = 1/u$ (and substituting $x$ back in):

$$I = xe^{1/x} - \int{\dfrac{e^u}{u} \ du}$$

We arrive at the final answer by substituting everything back in:

$$\boxed{\displaystyle I = xe^{1/x} - \operatorname{Ei} \left( \dfrac{1}{x} \right) + C}$$

I explain more of the small algebraic details [here](http://qr.ae/TUplYc), if any step is unclear.

---

A note on the solution: There's actually a much simpler solution I found after realizing the trig sub is redundant. Here it is:

Start by integrating by parts, with $dv = 1$:
$$\displaystyle I = xe^{1/x} - \int{\dfrac{-xe^{1/x}}{x^2} \ dx} = xe^{1/x} + \int{ \dfrac{e^{1/x}}{x}  \ dx}$$
We can substitute $u = 1/x \implies du = -1/x^2 \ dx$, noting that $x = 1/u$:
$$\displaystyle I = xe^{1/x} - \int{\dfrac{ue^{u}}{u^2} \ du} = xe^{1/x} - \int{\dfrac{e^{u}}{u} \ du}$$
$$\boxed{\displaystyle I = xe^{1/x} - \operatorname{Ei} \left( \dfrac{1}{x} \right) + C}$$

Answer (score 2):

One simple way to do it (if an approximate solution will do) is the following:

You know the Taylor series of $e^x$ is given by $e^x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!}+...$.

Therefore the Taylor series of $e^{1/x}$ is given by $e^{1/x} = 1 + \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{2!x^2} +...$

Now just integrate term-by term.

Comment: Okay. I can solve it then. Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

There is no definite formula for this you can use series expansion of $e^x$ to compute a numerical value.

$$e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+....$$
$$\int e^{1/x}=\int1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^22!}+\frac{1}{x^33!}+\frac{1}{x^44!}+.... \\
\int e^x= C + x + \ln x-\frac{1}{2!}\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{3!}\frac{1}{2x^2}-\frac{1}{3!}\frac{1}{3x^3}-...$$

Comment: So, There is no exact solution. Only approximated solution exists?

Comment: @MB17 No there is an exact solution, it just can't be expressed in terms of elementary functions

Comment: What is the exact solution then? In what way can it be expressed?

Comment: The more terms in the series you sum the more accurate the answer becomes.

Comment: Okay. I got it. Thank you:)

Comment: @Sonal_sqrt When the integral has limits $0$ to $\infty$, is it converge? How do we think about that

Comment: With those limits integral doesn't convergence. You can take the integral from a to b and have a and b go to zero and infinity respectively. And hence show that it doesn't converge.