# Integral of $\exp(-\frac{c_1}{x}-\frac{c_2}{x^2})$ on positive real line

Tags: definite-integrals, exponential-function, indefinite-integrals

Is it possible to find
$$
\int_{0}^{K}
\exp\left(-\,{c_{1} \over x} - {c_{2} \over x^{2}}\right)
\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
or at least a good approximation to it, where $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$ are positive and $K$ is a very large number $?$.

I tried to consider the change of variables
$-u = -c_{1}/x - c_{2}/x^{2}$ but to no avail.

**Note:** Approximation can include known functions such as *Erf*, or *Gamma*, if necessary.

Comment: I have tried to  [improve the readability of your question](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8588/290189)  by improving the [$\rm \LaTeX$](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189) code. It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question.  Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.

Comment: It seems that this problem has no easy closed form answer: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+0+to+K+exp%28-c_1%2Fx-c_2%2Fx%5E2%29dx std computation time exceeded

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 exactly. That is also what I was able to confirm with my Mathematica. It cannot find a closed form solution. Thats why I also added 'possibly a good approximate solution is welcomed'. I think this is just a very basic question which has possibly never been asked before.

Comment: Oops my bad.  I omitted that.  Thanks for reminder.  What about expending it in series?  Which $K$ get large, and remaining terms would converge quickly

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2545564/whats-the-integral-of-e1-x-dx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in large values of $K$, an asymptotic expansion is possible. Using integration by parts on the equivalent integral

$$I(c_1,c_2;K)=\int_{1/K}^{\infty}\exp[-c_1 t-c_2 t^2]\frac{dt}{t^2}$$

one can isolate the divergent terms as follows

$$I=(K-c_1\log K)e^{-c_1/K-c_2/K^2}+2c_2\int_{1/K}^{\infty}dt\exp[-c_1 t-c_2 t^2]-c_1^2\int_{1/K}^{\infty}dt\log t\exp[-c_1 t-c_2 t^2]-2c_1c_2\int_{1/K}^{\infty}t\log t\exp[-c_1 t-c_2 t^2]dt$$

This is an exact statement so far and all the integrals on the RHS possess a finite limit as $K\to \infty$. The first of the three integrals is easily obtainable:

$$\int_{1/K}^\infty dt\exp[-c_1 t-c_2 t^2]=\frac{e^{c_1^2/4c_2}}{\sqrt{c_2}}\text{erfc}\left(\frac{\sqrt{c_2}}{K}+\frac{c_1}{2\sqrt{c_2}}\right)$$

As a matter of fact, Mathematica states that all of these integrals can be evaluated in terms of derivatives of hypergeometric functions with respect to one of their arguments in the limit $K\to\infty$. To wit,

$$8c_2^{3/2}\int_{0}^{\infty}t\log t\exp[-c_1 t-c_2 t^2]dt=\sqrt{\pi } c_1 e^{\frac{c_1^2}{4 c_2}} \left(_1F_1^{(1,0,0)}\left(0,\frac{3}{2},-\frac{c_1^2}{4 c_2}\right)+(\log c_2+\gamma ) \text{erfc}\left(\frac{c_1}{2 \sqrt{c_2}}\right)-2+\log (4)\right)-2 \sqrt{c_2} \left(- ~_{1}F_1^{(1,0,0)}\left(1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{c_1^2}{4 c_2}\right)+\log c_2+\gamma \right)$$

and

$$-4c_2\int_{0}^{\infty}\log t\exp[-c_1 t-c_2 t^2]dt=\sqrt{\pi }\sqrt{c_2} e^{\frac{c_1^2}{4 c_2}} \left(_1F_1^{(1,0,0)}\left(0,\frac{1}{2},-\frac{\text{c1}^2}{4 c_2}\right)+(\log c_2+\gamma) \text{erfc}\left(\frac{c_1}{2 \sqrt{c_2}}\right)+\log 4\right)+c_1 ~_{1}F_1^{(1,0,0)}\left(1,\frac{3}{2},\frac{c_1^2}{4 c_2}\right)$$

where $_1F_1^{(1,0,0)}(a,b,z)=\frac{\partial}{\partial a}~_1F_1(a,b,z)$. Assembling these terms one obtains the first few terms of the asymptotic series for the result
$$I(c_1,c_2)\sim (K-c_1\log K)e^{-c_1/K-c_2/K^2}+2\sqrt{c_2}e^{c_1^2/4c_2}\text{erfc}\left(\frac{\sqrt{c_2}}{K}+\frac{c_1}{2\sqrt{c_2}}\right)-c_1^2\int_{0}^{\infty}dt\log t\exp[-c_1 t-c_2 t^2]-2c_1c_2\int_{0}^{\infty}t\log t\exp[-c_1 t-c_2 t^2]dt+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{\log K}{K}\right)$$

Comment: nice solution. So one time change of variables and two times integration by parts. I just realised that I also need the integrals from a to b namely not on the whole line. I am surprised that Mathematica cannot take those latter two integrals if the limit is from a to b instead of from 0 to infinity.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3924324/integral-of-the-exponential-function-exp-c-1x-c-2x2-c-3x-mu-beta I have this question too. Please let me know if you have any idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As said, series expansion could be the solution. Writing
$$\exp\left(-\frac{a}{x}-\frac{b}{x^2}\right)=1+\sum_{n=1}^p \frac {c_n}{n! \,x^n}=f(x)$$ the $c_n$'s would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & -a \\
 2 & a^2-2 b \\
 3 & -a^3+6 a b \\
 4 & a^4-12 b a^2+12 b^2 \\
 5 & -a^5+20 b a^3-60 b^2 a \\
 6 & a^6-30 b a^4+180 b^2 a^2-120 b^3 \\
 7 & -a^7+42 b a^5-420 b^2 a^3+840 b^3 a \\
 8 & a^8-56 b a^6+840 b^2 a^4-3360 b^3 a^2+1680 b^4 \\
 9 & -a^9+72 b a^7-1512 b^2 a^5+10080 b^3 a^3-15120 b^4 a \\
 10 & a^{10}-90 b a^8+2520 b^2 a^6-25200 b^3 a^4+75600 b^4 a^2-30240 b^5
\end{array}
\right)$$ and
$$\int\exp\left(-\frac{a}{x}-\frac{b}{x^2}\right)\,dx=1-a\log(x)-\sum_{n=2}^p \frac {c_n}{(n-1)\,n! \,x^{n-1}}+ C$$

For sure, there is a  problem with a lower bound equal to $0$.